# Enumerate Files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the files where the file names contains 14 digits.

[image]

```
  foreach (var file_path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"F:\apinvoice", "*.pdf"))
  {

  }
```

I need to get the files only which has "14" digits.

```
16032021133026
17032021120457
17032021120534
```

Comment: Add a where Statement to your enumeration to Check length of Filename

Comment: i need to enumerate the files which got 14 digits filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with regex where you specify pattern

you said you want 14 digits meaning it will ignore names like

```
 a1603202113302
```

because it contains letter

therefore pattern is

```
^[0-9]{14}$
```

and full code:

```
 Regex rx = new Regex("^[0-9]{14}$");
            
 Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(@"F:\apinvoice", "*.pdf")
     .Where(x => rx.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a list

```
List<string> list = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"F:\apinvoice", "*.pdf"))
List<string> whatyouwant = list.Where(l => l.Length == 14).ToList();
```

Comment: What purpose do your lists serve here?

Comment: Not Bad. But `l` is the full File name i think

Comment: I think you want to find files whose names are 18 characters, or whose filenames without the extension are 14 characters. Also, I don't think this code will compile. I believe `EnumerateFiles` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` which can't be implicitly cast to `List<string>`.

Comment: Won't compile, `l` is the fullName, `l.Length == 14` isn't the same as `I need to get the files only which has "14" digits.` because `abcdefghijklmn` has also a length of 14 but not a single digit.

Comment: That's true.  I would work with DirectoryInfo anyway and use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles to get the FileInfo objects which contain much more information (especially also the pure name of the file)

Comment: For the digit check you can add a condition to the where condition of the Linq list where the single string is checked for   yourstring.All(char.IsDigit) which returns true if string is empty or contains only digits.

Answer (score 0):

Since these seem to be timestamps, another thing you could do is this;

```cs
foreach (var file_path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"F:\apinvoice", "*.pdf"))
{
    DateTime dateTimeParsed;
    var dateTimeParsedSuccesfully = DateTime.TryParseExact(file_path, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeParsed);
    
    if(dateTimeParsedSuccesfully)
    {
        // Got a valid file, add it to a list or something.
    }
}
```

Also see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0

ofcourse often the timespan will often be at the end of a file, so if there are characters or something in front, you may want to pass `file_path.Substring(file_path.length - 14)` to `TryParseExact()`.